# Lost connection with Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure, mqtt, node-red, azure-iot-hub

I have Node-RED installed on my Raspberry Pi.

Connecting to Azure IoT Hub with Mosquitto using Node-RED.

Sometimes I'm in trouble because the connection with Azure IoT Hub is lost.

Checking with Log Analytics, the following error appears.

```
<ERROR>
This article describes the causes and solutions for 404104 DeviceConnectionClosedRemotely errors.
```

The cause is completely unknown, and I have not been able to find it even after investigating the countermeasures.

[image]

Comment: Could you please review the document link provided by JD Allen's response. The document's resolution steps may help you get unblocked. [troubleshoot-error-404104](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-troubleshoot-error-404104-deviceconnectionclosedremotely)

Comment: Hi.
Thank you for your answer.
I also knew this link.
How can I update the SAS token if it runs out?
I'm in trouble because I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Azure IOT doc, your SAS Token expired:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-troubleshoot-error-404104-deviceconnectionclosedremotely

Comment: Hi.
Thank you for your answer.
I also knew this link.
How can I update the SAS token if it runs out?
I'm in trouble because I don't understand.

Comment: Good question.  Not sure how the Azure IOT module in Node-Red sets this up. You may have to something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728649/how-to-generate-an-azure-sas-token-via-javascript-node-js

Comment: Thanks!! I don't know immediately, so read it carefully.

Comment: I will also comment later.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to generate your SAS token for a longer duration.

**Update:**

---

A user voice is being submitted by @Rio, please navigate to [When the connection of Azure IoT Hub from Node-RED is disconnected, an error occurs and it cannot be reconnected](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot/suggestions/40683982-when-the-connection-of-azure-iot-hub-from-node-red) and vote and comment your requirement in support of asking this feature.

---

> You have to re-create and re-configure the token in Node-Red when it
>   expires. Please refer to [Connect Node-Red to Azure IoT Edge](http://busbyland.com/connect-node-red-to-azure-iot-edge/)

**via Azure CLI: [az iot hub generate-sas-token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-iot-ext/iot/hub?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-cli-iot-ext-az-iot-hub-generate-sas-token)

Or

via using code as commented by @JD Allen or like using c# shown below,

To get a basic understanding on how SAS Token refresh based on SharedAccessKey , please see this C# code snippet. Please make sure you have IoTHub connection string and deviceId as well. For more reading please refer [azure-iot-sdk-csharp](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/master/iothub/device/src/DeviceAuthenticationWithSakRefresh.cs)

```
namespace Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client
{
    // Implementing SAS Token refresh based on a SharedAccessKey (SAK).
    internal class DeviceAuthenticationWithSakRefresh : DeviceAuthenticationWithTokenRefresh
    {
        private IotHubConnectionString _connectionString;

        public DeviceAuthenticationWithSakRefresh(
            string deviceId, 
            IotHubConnectionString connectionString) : base(deviceId)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }

        protected override Task<string> SafeCreateNewToken(string iotHub, int suggestedTimeToLive)
        {
            var builder = new SharedAccessSignatureBuilder()
            {
                Key = _connectionString.SharedAccessKey,
                TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(suggestedTimeToLive),
            };

            if (_connectionString.SharedAccessKeyName == null)
            {
                builder.Target = "{0}/devices/{1}".FormatInvariant(
                    iotHub, 
                    WebUtility.UrlEncode(DeviceId));
            }
            else
            {
                builder.KeyName = _connectionString.SharedAccessKeyName;
                builder.Target = _connectionString.Audience;
            }

            return Task.FromResult(builder.ToSignature());
        }
    }
}
```

**Also please do refer the [Protocol specifics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-security#protocol-specifics) doc.

> The [Azure IoT SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-sdks)s automatically generate tokens when connecting to
>   the service. In some cases, the Azure IoT SDKs do not support all the
>   protocols or all the authentication methods.

**Also refer to similar GitHub issues [sas token renewal#613](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/613), [Renew SAS token used by Azure Iot Hub DeviceClient #1127](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/1127)

Comment: But how would someone do this in Node-Red??

Comment: I have never used C#.
First, let's check.
Have you encountered this problem with Node-RED?

Comment: For how long (duration) was the first SAS key generated?

Comment: Connections are often lost about 30 minutes after starting Node-RED.
Occasionally, the connection will last for 4 to 5 days.

Comment: @Rio, Could you please create a [User Voice Request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot/filters/new) on this topic with your requirements in detail with a good Title. I will make sure to do a follow-up.Let me know the final posted link here, once you have submitted the request.

Comment: @SatishBoddu-MSFT
Thank you for your reply.
I have filled out the User Voice Request.
Isn't what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/321918-azure-iot/suggestions/40683982-when-the-connection-of-azure-iot-hub-from-node-red

Comment: @Rio, Thank you! I have added the comment. Please bookmark this URL to followup on the request. I will also followup internally with Product Team. We have to gain more number of votes and comments to make it approved by the PG team. Thanks again for your contribution.

Comment: @Rio, Please accept my updated response as 'Answer' so that it is helpful to others as well looking with similar question and there by voting the user voice.