# Extend token expiration when uploading large blobs on Azure Blob Storage

Tags: javascript, file-upload, azure-blob-storage, sas-token

I have an API in place, that generates and returns SAS tokens for a given blob name. Then on my front end application I am handling the upload using the response (credentials) provided by the API, together with the file selected directly through the browser.

I am using the *blockBlobClient.uploadData* function. This works fine and uploads finish successfully, however I've noticed that the SAS token gets reused for all blocks being uploaded and processed as part of that blob (I need to be prepared for > 1GB files), hence if for instance my server returns a 5 min expiration token and my user's connection is slow or gets partially interrupted, the file might take more than 5 minutes to finish upload and this will eventually throw an error to the browser from the Azure Blob API and file upload will stop.

I know that of course one approach would be to just issue longer-life tokens to account for those scenarios, or maybe, set the expiration based on the file size; but I would like to know if there is an efficient and not that complex way of having the token's expiration extended somehow (without losing my current upload progress for that blob), so that the file can get properly uploaded even if the first expiration is reached. Haven't found anything in the docs so far.

I am using NodeJs for my backend API, with the **@azure/storage-blob** npm package (which I also use on my frontend app)

Hope that was clear enough.

Thanks for any help that can be provided!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
Inject new SAS for an ongoing uploading. Sometimes a SAS will be expiry before a large uploading finishes, for this scenario, we want to request a new SAS token during the uploading instead of starting a new uploading.

Try with this code to update SAS for uploading large file .

```
async function upload() {
  const sasStore = new SasStore();

  const pipeline = Azure.StorageURL.newPipeline(
    new Azure.AnonymousCredential()
  );
  // Inject SAS update policy factory into current pipeline
  pipeline.factories.unshift(new SasUpdatePolicyFactory(sasStore));

  const url = "https://jsv10.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myblob";
  const blockBlobURL = new Azure.BlockBlobURL(
    `${url}${await sasStore.getValidSASForBlob(url)}`, // A SAS should start with "?"
    pipeline
  );

  const file = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
  await Azure.uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob(
    Azure.Aborter.none,
    file,
    blockBlobURL,
    {
      maxSingleShotSize: 4 * 1024 * 1024
    }
  );
}
/ azblob is default exported entry when importing Azure Storage Blob SDK by <script src="azure-storage.blob.js"></script>
// You can also import SDK by npm package with const Azure = require("@azure/storage-blob")
const Azure = azblob;

// SasStore is a class to cache SAS for blobs
class SasStore {
  constructor() {
    this.sasCache = {};
  }

  // Get a valid SAS for blob
  async getValidSASForBlob(blobURL) {
    if (
      this.sasCache[blobURL] &&
      this.isSasStillValidInNext2Mins(this.sasCache[blobURL])
    ) {
      return this.sasCache[blobURL];
    } else {
      return (this.sasCache[blobURL] = await this.getNewSasForBlob(blobURL));
    }
  }


// Return true if "se" section in SAS is still valid in next 2 mins
  isSasStillValidInNext2Mins(sas) {
    const expiryStringInSas = new URL(`http://host${sas}`).searchParams.get(
      "se"
    );
    return new Date(expiryStringInSas) - new Date() >= 2 * 60 * 1000;
  }

  // Get a new SAS for blob, we assume a SAS starts with a "?"
  async getNewSasForBlob(blobURL) {
    // TODO: You need to implement this
    return "?newSAS";
  }
}

class SasUpdatePolicyFactory {
  constructor(sasStore) {
    this.sasStore = sasStore;
  }
  create(nextPolicy, options) {
    return new SasUpdatePolicy(nextPolicy, options, this.sasStore);
  }
}

class SasUpdatePolicy extends Azure.BaseRequestPolicy {
  constructor(nextPolicy, options, sasStore) {
    super(nextPolicy, options);
    this.sasStore = sasStore;
  }

  async sendRequest(request) {
    const urlObj = new URL(request.url);
    const sas = await this.sasStore.getValidSASForBlob(
      `${urlObj.origin}${urlObj.pathname}`
    );
    new URL(`http://hostname${sas}`).searchParams.forEach((value, key) => {
      urlObj.searchParams.set(key, value);
    });

    // Update request URL with latest SAS
    request.url = urlObj.toString();

    return this._nextPolicy.sendRequest(request);
  }
}
```

Follow this [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-js/wiki/Customize-HTTP-Pipeline-and-Policies-to-Dynamic-Inject-SAS-During-Uploading) code for more details
.To create new SAS refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51728649/how-to-generate-an-azure-sas-token-via-javascript-node-js)

**Solution 2:**
Instead of uploading  large file, upload file in **chunks**[method split large file into smaller sizes]. upload the file in chunks so that bigger files can be uploaded without reading them in completely in a single go.

More details refer this [document](https://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/)